# Django action (not model data directly) HTML view and API validation keeping a DRY rule

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I would like to create an API for my project.

The models:

```
class Offer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    data = models.TextField()

class Bid(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey()
    offer = models.ForeignKey()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Here's the simplified example (as there are more checks)
Both Offer & Bid users can cancel the Bid.

In my standard (HTML) view:

```
def cancel_bid(request, pk):
    do_some checks_if request.user_is_either_Bid_or+Offer)creator()
    check_if_Bid_has_been_created_for_less_than_5_minutes()
    #as user can cancel his bid within 5 minutes
```

Now the same must be applied to Django Rest Framework (permissions or serializers).

The problem is that I need to return error messages and codes displayed in both json error response (when using api) and in my HTML views.

I have created a cancel(self, user, other kwargs) in my Bid model where check for these are performed and my custom PermissionDenied(message, code) is returned. Then in DRF and my views I simply put:

```
bid = Bid.objects.get(pk=pk)
    try:
        bid.cancel(user):
    except PermissionDenied as e:
        messages.error(request, e.message)
        # or return HttpResponseForbidden(e.message)
```

in django rest framework:

```
class OrderCancelView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, pk):
        try:
            order.cancel(request.user)
        except PermissionDenied as e:
            raise serializers.PermissionDenied(detail=e.message)
```

There are more actions performed in my clean() method not pointed out here.. which 
makes the method very complex. 
For example:
If offer expires all bids except the first one (earliest) are cancelled.. so there is no user,
as it's being made by system. I have to omit user checks then.. and so on.

What are your thoughts on this ? What is the best Django way of doing this kind of "action" validation and keeping DRY rule?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you've already made a good start, you just need to structure your `cancel` method on the model so that it has all of the information it needs to execute the business logic. If your logic has to be the same between DRF and the normal view code then I would extract all the business logic into the model. You might have to give it lots of arguments so that it can make all of the correct decisions, but that's better than having to repeat the logic twice.